# Display current webpage size

Tags: javascript, asp.net, dom

Is there an easy way to show the size of an aspx webpage in bytes (i.e length not screen size) - to save clicking File..Properties in the browser.

Possibly some javascript method, or a way of getting it from the Response object perhaps?

Comment: In the end I implemented this with an HTTP HEAD request and read Content-Length  - javascript xmlhttp.getResponseHeader("Content-Length")

Answer (score 0):

Look at firebug.  Under the NET tab it will show you the size of all the files downloaded for a page in bytes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery to get the number of characters in the  element with the following snippet.  In most encodings, one character will be one byte.

```
$('html').html().length
```

It's worth noting that this measurement won't include the doctype declaration, but if you're using the same doctype in all pages on the site, you could count the number of bytes in the doctype and add that to the length derived from the above count.